# Redux Toolkit w TypeScript: How can I unwrap the type of AsyncThunk

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I hava a action called `getIndexingConfig`

```
export const getIndexingConfig = createAsyncThunk(
  "settings/getIndexingConfig",
  async () => {
    const {
      indexingConfiguration,
      groupIndexingConfiguration
    } = await sdkClient.getIndexingConfiguration().promise();

    return {
      indexingMode: indexingConfiguration?.thingIndexingMode,
      groupIndexingMode: groupIndexingConfiguration?.thingGroupIndexingMode
    };
  }
);
```

The type of it is, according to TS compiler

```
const getIndexingConfig: AsyncThunk<
  {
    indexingMode: string | undefined;
    groupIndexingMode: string | undefined;
  },
  void,
  {}
>;
```

I wonder how I can get the return value's type from it. i.e.

```
 {
    indexingMode: string | undefined;
    groupIndexingMode: string | undefined;
  }
```

I try to use `ReturnType<typeof getIndexingConfig>` but it doesn't seem to unwrap the thunk to give me the return value's type.

Answer (score -1):

```
export type ITSUnpackedPromiseLike<T> =
    T extends ITSResolvable<infer U> ? U :
        T
    ;

ITSUnpackedPromiseLike<ReturnType<typeof getIndexingConfig>>
```

Comment: what is `ITSResolvable`?

Comment: type ITSResolvable<R> = R | PromiseLike<R>;